# Why does the video recorded by a falling, rotating camera seem to stabilize?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, camera

Here is a video of a GoPro falling from a plane: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrxPuk0JefA

Any idea what is happening when the image "stabilizes" around 0:35? I think it is because the camera's tangential velocity approaches the speed of the GoPro's rolling shutter.

Follow-up question:

- Why is the image skewed with the left side skewed "up" and the right side skewed "down?"

A challenge:

- Find the axis of rotation (with supporting diagram and explanation of how it was computed).

Comment: Also, I'm inclined to agree that the stabilizing might be due to aliasing due to the rotation of the camera, but I'll await the judgement of people who look further in depth.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75709/2451

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: No way, that was awesome. I suppose the camera was dropped accidentally...

Comment: But the pig... It was eating the camera. They're not supposed to eat cameras.

Comment: I'm almost certain the "stability" was simply a matter of the framerate.  As you listen to the video you can hear it spinning even when it appears not to be.  Extract out the audio, do a spectral analysis and you'll find that the frequency of the audio is some integer multiple of the framerate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something that the older analog TVs had called a vertical hold.

My answer is that the frames per minute taken by the camera is equalizing the rotation/spinning of the camera. It was chance that they got the ground in the frame. You can kind of get the same effect when filming a helicopter's rotor and it looks stationary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxddi8m_mzk